# Difference between User and System Installer of Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio code offers User and System Installer but I have not found any description about the differences between these two options.

Could someone please shed a light on this for me?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

> #### User setup for Windows
>
> Announced last release, the user setup package for Windows is now available on stable. Installing the user setup does not require Administrator privileges as the location will be under your user Local AppData (LOCALAPPDATA) folder. User setup also provides a smoother background update experience.
>
> [Download User Setup](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=win64user)
>
> If you are a current user of the system-wide Windows setup, you will be prompted to install user setup, which we recommend using from now on. Don't worry, all your settings and extensions will be kept during the transition. During installation, you will also be prompted to uninstall the system-wide setup.

Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_user-setup-for-windows

Comment: BTW, when running user-installer as admin it prompts `"This User Installer is not meant to be run as an Administrator. If you would like to install VS Code for all users in this system, download the System Installer instead..."`

Comment: FYI the "user" setup did not work for me (unable to write on destination folder), I downloaded the "system" setup and it installed fine.

Comment: Why is the user setup version recommended and pushed as the default one to install?

Comment: Does User setup mean that if I have multiple users on the same machine, it needs to be installed once on each users folder? I'd rather go for one system install that's available for all users!

Comment: Can someone explain why this user install is the default?

Comment: @AFract did you change the destination folder to `C:\Program Files\` or some folder that needs elevated privileges? Because the point of the user installer is that it installs the program to a user directory like AppData, assuming it does not need any elevations and thus doesn't ask for it.

Comment: @Pedro77 Because such editors are usually heavily user-customized tools anyway (key bindings, behaviors, color schemes) and it provides less hassle for the average non-admin-user if the program is just running smoothly and always-up-to-date without any admin privileges required at any time.

Comment: @LWChris Well, virtually all modern browsers are heavily user-customized (extensions, settings) and are automatically updated via background processes (services) and have no issues with installing into `C:\Program Files` whatsoever. So what's the point in installing the program into separate folder once for each user?

Comment: @izogfif Yes, and they use the same mechanics. Chrome for example asks for privileges, and if you deny, it'll install into `AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application`. Profiles are in AppData as well. The only difference is that VS Code has two different bootstrappers for the two choices, and Chrome has just one that switches.

Comment: @Pedro77 In general, if you are working in a Office, most likely you don't have admin right and control under Active Directory or control by the IT department, windows installer will get so trouble when you have to install or update further, the system installer will prompt every time for admin login, but user installer don't have this limitations. So why MS suggest use the user install. But window installer also have its advantage for administrator deploy or pre install in an enterprise environment. For home user, for sure it has no difference because you always has admin right.

Comment: @LWChris Google probably uses a decent installer and Microsoft the crappy WiX Toolset. :)

Comment: @Cheung
There's a reason for not having admin rights. Could it possibly be that you must not install anything yourself?

Comment: Up-to-date reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows#_user-setup-versus-system-setup

Answer (score 54):

I installed the user version side-by-side with the system version with no problems. The basic differences between the two is that the system version installs on the file system like every other app. The user install is basically a click-once (or web installer) version that installs in the User folder of the machine.

The settings made to VS Code in the system version save for Everybody on the computer and the user version the settings are only for the user. I find that the behavior of the user version is a bit annoying for me because I have reasons to want to open multiple copies of VS Code at the same time and the user version only allows one instance. Otherwise, there's not really anything different between the two as far as I can tell.

Comment: On a side note, I installed the user version today and it allows more than one instance.

Comment: System Installer Version allows multiple instances too.

Comment: Thanks for this. I hate the idea of installing software to my user folder, and I have no idea why Microsoft of all companies would promote this as a standard, so I'll be using the system installer.

Comment: If you have a truly multi-user Windows environment, user installs make sense, because users can individually install extensions, decide when to update versions, etc., but if you are using windows as a single power-user the system install is probably better.

Comment: @LightCC I have installed VS Code user install for two users on Windows Server 2012 in the hopes that they would be able to install updates independently, but the updater still tries to close the other user's running instances of code.exe and fails with 'Access denied'. Otherwise users can install their own extensions independently even in the system install, user settings are saved in Appdata in both cases.

Comment: @LightCC Thank you for the explanation, so does this mean that when you create a new user, VSCode-User will open up without any extensions installed by the admin?

Comment: @LightCC Doesn't make sense for me. You should be able to install individual extensions without multiple IDE installations if this is really needed. The extensions and settings go to user path, the IDE to program path.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan Yeah, that makes sense as well. I guess the user install is really intended to allow common users to install for themselves without admin permission, though it sounds like there may be some glitches.

Comment: is their anything like perforamance or speed or somethign?

Answer (score 6):

Many companies (like mine) dont allow Admin privileges, I think that's the main point so you  can still install VSC with the user installer

Comment: Many companies (like yours) don't allow admin privileges because you're not allowed to install anything.

Answer (score -1):

After user version of Visual Studio Code is downloaded, make `cmd` in the download folder and run a command below, replacing the correct version in the VS ode installation file name:

> runas /trustlevel:0x20000 ./VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.74.3.exe

start the command below in order to check which trust levels are supported:

> runas /showtrustlevels