# VS Code: Why does the User Installer warn about administrator privileges?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I've read that when installing Visual Studio Code, the User Installer is recommended because it installs to the Users folder and does not require administrator privileges, but apparently it also allows for better background updating of the program.

However, when I try to install the User Installer, I get the following message:

> This User Installer is not meant to be run as an Administrator. If you would like to install VS Code for all users in this system, download the System Installer instead.

I tried installing it once before by accepting this, but the title bar of VS Code will show "Administrator," so I'm wondering what was the point of the User Installer if it still warns me of administrator privileges and still installs with them? If it installs to the Users folder, why would it even show this warning message? Is there a way to avoid this?

If not, will this cause any issues, like slowdowns or such? Do I still get the benefit of the smoother updating that the User Installer supposedly gives?

Answer (score 2):

If you log in as an admin user and try to install the user version of vs code you get the warning. If you go ahead and install then your vs code won't be able to get update notifications or be able to auto update. If this is a problem for you the solution is to not run the install directly but to run it as follows:

`runas /machine:x86 /trustlevel:0x20000 vscodeinstaller.exe`

The above will run the always x86 installer exe and install your selected version as a regular user. trustlevel x20000.

Answer found at this link:
[How to install application as regular user if your are logged in as Administrative User](https://superuser.com/questions/1749696/parameter-is-incorrect-when-using-runas-with-trustlevel-after-windows-11-22h2)

Not as simple as I had hoped. After install that avoids the warning you are still running code as admin because you are in the admin group.
So... still no auto update and you still get that annoying warning.

Make a shortcut with:

`C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /machine:amd64 /trustlevel:0x20000 "C:\Users\brook\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe"`

Put it on your desktop and run it.

Windows will push all your "open with code" double click on files into the running version.

Comment: The `runas /machine:x86 /trustlevel:0x20000 VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.86.0.exe` did the trick for me, in a *Win11 64b* machine. I still had no need of the second part.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51834561/1028230), I see that [visualstudio.com](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_user-setup-for-windows) says:

> If you are a current user of the system-wide Windows setup, you will be prompted to install user setup, which we recommend using from now on.

That suggests to me that the error message we've both seen will soon be obsolete.

That is, when the installer sees you logged in as admin (which conventionally means you wouldn't be coding), it assumes you wanted this now-intended-to-be-deprecated use case where you're installing once on the system for ALL users, which the user setup won't do.

You've probably seen installers ask this: "*Do you want to install for all users or just your user?*" If all users, it asks you to give the installer admin permissions and installs in Program Files. If just you, it installs in a user path (like VS Code for users does: `C:\Users\thySmyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`).

Instead of a unified system/user install, VS Code seems to have broken it into two.

Make sense? If you're installing to code when logged in as admin, like on a remote box or something, that might still be a bit of an admin smell, but the user setup sh/w/ould otherwise be fine.

If you wanted to install for *every user on the box*, which you could do with your fancy admin permissions, you'd need to get a different installer. That's all.