# Why am I getting the error: An error occurred while trying to create a file in the destination directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know why I am getting this error suddenly whilst using vs code. Please help me, Thanks in advance.

P.S(I don't think files can be created in an exe right? I'm not sure after seeing this. Maybe do I have to specify where the file should be created and if yes, please tell me how. Else I'm looking for another answer)

(Edit): I tried downloading the system installation instead of the user installation. The system installer installs for all users on the system and needs administrator privileges unlike the user installer which install vs code only the particular user installing it.

Thanks, Codestrip

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6lri.jpg)

Comment: what do you do at that moment, steps please

Comment: Sorry just a newbie here so please pardon me. Btw I added the information and the differences.

Comment: what do I need to do to reproduce the error, if you want to reply to a user that is not the author use the format `@username` as the start of the comment, he then always gets a notification

Comment: Ok, sure @rioV8

Comment: I'm getting the same error. VS Code on Windows was working fine. After some recent update the error started popping up. It shows up a few minutes after I start Code, not right away, and then every now and then. I have user setup, currently at v1.66.1. It seems like it's trying to install some uninstaller in a folder where it doesn't have permissions.

Comment: I think I was using the same version at the time, maybe it was a bug but it happened while tried running vs code user installation as an admin @SteveNay

Comment: @rioV8 I think at that time I tried running the user installation as an admin.

Comment: Check this thread [VS Code: Why does the User Installer warn about administrator privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997406/vs-code-why-does-the-user-installer-warn-about-administrator-privileges)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my solution for this was to set it to always start as administrator, I don't feel like reinstalling vscode (newly installed)
It's not a great solution for those who have multiple users, but I got rid of the error.

Ah, I saw that was a problem within User Permission, there were only 2 options checked. https://prnt.sc/uV-bF_q52Y3Y

I hope my solution will help you.

Answer (score 3):

> If you run your "vscode" as admin then you won't see this error
> anymore.
>
> 1. Go to your "vscode" install location
>
> - If not sure then open the start menu.
> - Write vscode.
> - Right click on the icon and click "Open File Location".
> - In a new window there will be again an icon for the "vscode" right click on the icon
> - Again and click "open file location".
> - In another window, there will be an actual vscode's "exe" file.

> 2. Right-click on this file and go to the "send" > "send on desktop" option.
> 3. On the Desktop right-click on the icon and go to the properties
> 4. Click on Advance Option and Check the "Run as Admin" Option
> 5. Click Apply and Ok.
> 6. Now if you want Right Click on this icon again and select "pin to taskbar".
>
> Hopefully, you won't see this error again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. But I fixed it. just go to this link and add take ownership to your context menu.
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3841-add-take-ownership-context-menu-windows-10-a.html
After adding take ownership just go to vs code main directory and right-click on the Microsoft VS Code folder then press take ownership. After that your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error.
I tried remove the folder `Microsoft VS Code` inside `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\Programs`, and problem seems resloved